# Textbox not showing up on first tabpage

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I'm making an application that requires me to dynamically add tabPages with a textBox and a label on each tabPage (the default configuration has no tabPages in the tabControl). On the first tab page, there is no textBox showing up. Ironically, the label is always there...just no textbox. When I try to access it in another function via `tabControlLanguageTranslations.SelectedTab.GetChildAtPoint(translationTextbox)`, it comes up null. This problem only happens on the first tabPage.

Here is the code that creates the textboxes and labels:

```
foreach (var lang in languages)
            {
                TabPage tempTab = new TabPage(lang.shortName);

                TextBox TextBoxStringTranslation = new TextBox();
                Label LabelTranslation = new Label();

                TextBoxStringTranslation.Location = translationTextbox;
                TextBoxStringTranslation.Width = 300;
                TextBoxStringTranslation.Height = 200;
                TextBoxStringTranslation.Multiline = true;
                TextBoxStringTranslation.TextChanged += TextBoxStringTranslation_TextChanged;

                LabelTranslation.Location = new Point(10, 10);
                LabelTranslation.Width = 100;
                LabelTranslation.Text = "Translation:";

                tempTab.Controls.Add(TextBoxStringTranslation);
                tempTab.Controls.Add(LabelTranslation);
                langTabs.Add(tempTab);

                tabControlLanguageTranslations.TabPages.Add(langTabs[langTabs.Count -1]);

                tempTab = null; //destroys the object because passing by reference would give us hell
            }
```

Comment: I just wanted to destroy the reference because I was afraid that there might be a pointer hanging around somewhere in the .NET framework causing all of those textboxes to be the same. Regardless, commenting it out the dereference doesn't change anything.

Comment: What is `translationTextBox` equal to first time round? Subsequent times round?

Comment: @Graham translationTextbox is a Point. It's admittedly a bit poorly named but it is always equal to (10, 40)

Comment: I suggest you set a break point and single step through code. Also check `tabControlLanguageTranslations.SelectedTab.Controls` (instead of `GetChildAtPoint`) for existence of added textbox and label using debugger. Otherwise not much anyone can do because there is too much unseen code...

Comment: The scope of the `tempTab` ends with the closing curly. The object lives as long as it is sitting in the `langTabs` and or the `Tab.TabPages` collection.  - As it is your code works fine __here__. Therefore you must have something else somewhere else. Try to add the explicit local `Point translationTextbox = new Point(10, 40);`

Comment: @TaW I am using that explicit local globally in this class (it is private so nothing else is interfering with it). Even as a readonly Point, I still have the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't really expect it, but mutable structs hit you when you least expect them. But as I said, your code works fine here.